# woocommerce_rest_authentication_error in local server

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, xampp, wamp

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
    "message": "Consumer key is invalid.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Used WAMP & XAMPP local servers

Steps followed for troubleshooting:

1. Enable the legacy REST API is checked
2. I have made new rest api and applied the same consumer key
3. I created new admin and tried
4. I replace htaccess with default wordpress
5. I have upgrade both wordpress and woocommerce version to latest
6. I have disabled all other plugins
7. Used OAuth 1.0. Just added the consumer key and consumer secret and send the request

I still haven't solved the issue.

Comment: Please double check your consumer key, it is showing that consumer key is invalid.

Comment: I have checked and regenerated also. But still the issue persists

Comment: I have solved the issue by changing the signature key to HMAC-SHA1

Now it's 200 OK